# Azure Boards, how to use each work item type?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-boards

which one is most specialized option, and which one is most generalized option?
Option: Task/Epic/features/Product Backlog Items

Sprints will have prioritized list of:
Option:  Items/ releases/sub sprints/ work items

Comment: It feels like this question would be more on topic on either [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) or [Web Apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There is a planning hierarchy which depends on the Process you've selected for your Project.

Basic:

```
  Epic                 <- Portfolio backlog
  |
  +- Issue             <- Product Backlog  <-+
     |                                       |- Sprint Backlog
     +- Task                               <-+
```

Scrum:

```
  Epic                 <-+
  |                      |- Portfolio Backlog
  +- Feature           <-+
     |
     +- PBI            <- Product backlog  <-+
        |                                    |- Sprint Backlog
        +- Task                            <-+
```

Agile:

```
  Epic                 <-+
  |                      |- Portfolio Backlog
  +- Feature           <-+
     |
     +- User Story     <- Product backlog  <-+
        |                                    |- Sprint Backlog
        +- Task                            <-+
```

CMMI:

```
  Epic                 <-+
  |                      |- Portfolio Backlog
  +- Feature           <-+
     |
     +- Requirement    <- Product backlog  <-+
        |                                    |- Sprint Backlog
        +- Task                            <-+
```

The Bug work item can either be at the same level as PBI/User Story/Requirement/Issue or at the level of Tasks. This can be configured at the

In general, you'd plan really big ideas at the Portfolio Level, but make sure you refine these to the level of PBI/User Story/Requirement/Issue. These are the ordered (I don't like the word prioritized) list of items we call the Product Backlog in Scrum.

Then at the sprint level you select one or more PBI/User Story/Requirement/Issue, assign them to a Sprint iteration and optionally break them down into tasks. I tend to not use the Task Board that much anymore, instead I rely on the Boards view at the Product Backlog level.

The logical concept of a "Release" doesn't exist in Azure DevOps. You can optionally create a child-iteration to add the concept, but that then is your own interpretation. You could also use Tags on work items to represent releases, or add a custom field to any of there work items to indicate a target release. You can even add a custom work item type you'd call "Release" a associate other work items to it.

The "Release" hub in Azure DevOps represents the technical process the Increment (produced artifacts) go through to be made available to your end users. Azure DevOps assumes you'd want to do some form of Continuous Integration & releasing. When you do that the concept of a "release" becomes a lot more technical and doesn't make much sense planning-wise anymore.

When you go down the route of customizing, you'll quickly find out how massively configurable Azure DevOps is, but you'd have to provide your users with your own process guidance. Concepts can be added in many different ways, and each will have its advantages or disadvantages.

See:

- [Basic Workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/get-started/plan-track-work?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops&tabs=basic-process#tabpanel_1_basic-process)
- [Scrum Process Workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/scrum-process-workflow?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops)
- [Agile Process Workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/agile-process-workflow?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops)
- [CMMI Process Workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/cmmi-process-workflow?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops)
- [Show bugs on backlogs and boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/show-bugs-on-backlog?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&bc=%2fazure%2fdevops%2fboards%2fbreadcrumb%2ftoc.json&toc=%2fazure%2fdevops%2fboards%2ftoc.json&view=azure-devops)